# After moving project to new server I get an error Can't locate assembly. How do I fix?

Tags: c#

We were forced to move our projects to another server and now I get an error that an assembly can't be found.  The SA brought up the old server so I could look around.  When I browse the Solution Explorer and look at properties for the reference it has a path but on the new server it does not and it won't let me insert it.

I tried going to solution properties/reference paths and add the path but that didn't help either.

Comment: remove and reinsert

Comment: What assembly is missing?

Comment: The assembly isn't missing, it's in a new location with different file path but it is a class that was shared on this forum or another called ExtensionHelper.

Comment: Remove and reinsert worked.  I got a bunch of warnings that certain columns are never used but from what I can tell everything is working.

Thank you.